# Google App-Gmail Unable to set from. Gmail replacing from address when sending via swiftmailer SMTP transport (PHP)

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

Hello and thank you for any help in advance.

I'm using swiftmailer, SMTP transport method to send email from my PHP script.

Sending the message is fine. It works.

The problem is, no matter what I set the FROM,REPLYTO,SENDER settings to, The email comes through as the GMAIL mailbox (ME - me@mydomain.com) instead.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('imap.gmail.com', 465,'ssl')
    ->setUsername($login)
    ->setPassword($password)
    ;
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
    ->setFrom(array('test@testdomain.com' => 'test mcttest'))
    ->setReplyTo(array('test@testdomain.com' => 'test mcttest'))
    ->setSender('test@testdomain.com')
    ->setTo(array($to))
    ->setBody(wordwrap($body, 70))
    ->setContentType('text/plain')
    ;
```

So the email goes through fine, but instead of being from **TEST-test@testdomain.com** as the sender... it's **ME-me@mydomain.com**

I switch to a separate (non-gmail) SMTP server to test and the email went through fine, without any problems... definitely think it's a GMAIL thing.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is Gmail that changes the sender e-mail address to be the same of the account you are authenticating. There is no workaround for that, except maybe becoming a paid customer of Google Apps.

Comment: We use the paid Google Apps and get the same thing.  I'm currently setting up my own SMTP server so I do the VERP thing with our GMail accounts.  But I think I need to get my DNS configured with the proper SPF record so I can send from both smtp.gmail.com and my SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I've come across the same issue. But as a bit of an insight, I think this is actually a Swiftmailer issue.

There are other libraries and frameworks (Codeignitor pops in my head) that will let you use Googlemails SMTP servers while masking the from address as an email address of your choosing.

Comment: Are you sure?  I think this is a Google thing,  If you go through smtp.gmail.com, it "cleanses" all the from/return info.  I can understand this for totally different addresses (the account is me@gmail.com and you're trying to send you@gmail.com), but for plus addresses (me+alternate@gmail.com) or Google Apps domains (me@mydomain.com account using you@mydomain.com for return), it should be allowable.