# How to change setFrom in symfony2 mailer from defoult to setted in form fields

Tags: php, symfony, mailer

After filing form and submit in recieving emails, field 'from' is always default setted from parameters.ymn instead of typed in form field
 `$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()->setFrom(array($Register->getEmail() => $Register->getName()))`
I use gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should rather use your own email service to send emails like this, gmail overrides all from settings

[How to set 'FROM' property using Swiftmailer with Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128472/how-to-set-from-property-using-swiftmailer-with-gmail)
[Google App-Gmail Unable to set from. Gmail replacing from address when sending via swiftmailer SMTP transport (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954725/google-app-gmail-unable-to-set-from-gmail-replacing-from-address-when-sending-v)